# Prove that a series converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $(x_n)$ and $(y_n)$ be sequences such that the sequence of partial sums of the series
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x_n}$ is bounded, and furthermore the series

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty{|y_n - y_{n+1}|} $$ converges, while $y_n \to 0 $ for $x \to \infty$

Prove that the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty{x_n{y_n}}$ converges.

**Hint:** use the summation by parts formula

Comment: Are you familiar with the Abel transform or, alternatively, do you know how to rewrite $\sum x_ny_n$ using the differences $|y_n-y_{n-1}|?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:**

1. Check that
   $$
   \sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_ny_n= y_N X_n-\sum\limits_{n=1}^N X_n(y_{n+1}-y_n)
   $$
   where $X_n=\sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_n$
2. Since $X_n$ is bounded
   $$
   \sum\limits_{n=1}^N x_ny_n\leq M(|y_N|+\sum\limits_{n=1}^N|y_{n+1}-y_n|)
   $$
   for some $M\geq 0$
3. It is remains to take a limit $N\to\infty$.